# Is it possible to store authentication token in a separate file?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0

I am building a command line tool using python that interfaces with an RESTful api. The API uses oauth2 for authentication. Rather than asking for access_token every time user runs the python tool. Can I store the access_token in some way so that I can use it till its lifespan? If it is then how safe it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the access token in a file on your user's desktop.

You can do so using a storage. Assuming you use `oauth2client`:

```
# Reading credentials
store = oauth2client.file.Storage(cred_path)
credentials = store.get()

# Writing credentials
creds = client.AccessTokenCredentials(access_token, user_agent)
creds.access_token = access_token
creds.refresh_token = refresh_token
creds.client_id = client_id
creds.client_secret = client_secret

# For some reason it does not save all the credentials,
# so write them to a json file manually instead
with open(credential_path, "w") as f:
    f.write(creds.to_json)
```

In terms of security, I would not see much of a threat here as these access tokens will be on a user's desktop. If someone wants to get their access token, they would need to have read access to that file for that time frame. However, if they can already do that, they most likely also can use your script to send them a copy of the user's access token every time it is authenticated. But take my word lightly as I'm not a professional in that area. See [information security stack exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com).

A [post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/72475/should-we-store-accesstoken-in-our-database-for-oauth2) in information security stack exchange did talk about this:

> these tokens give access to some fairly privileged information about your users.

However, the question was addressed to a database instead.

In conclusion, you *can* keep it in a file. (But take my word with a grain of salt)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to store it on the service side or locally?

Since your tool interfaces RESTful API, which is stateless, meaning that no information is stored between different requests to API, you actually need to provide access token every time your client accesses any of the REST endpoints. I am maybe missing some of the details in your design, but access tokens should be used only for authorization, since your user is already authenticated if he has a token. This is why tokens are valid only for a certain amount of time, usually 1 hour.

So you need to provide a state either by using cookie (web interface) or storing the token locally (Which is what you meant). However, you should trigger the entire oauth flow every time a user logs in to your client (authenticating user and providing a new auth token) otherwise you are not utilizing the benefits of oauth.